# File Shares Azure AD without Azure AD DS

Tags: azure, fileshare

Im, looking to move on premise file servers into Azure as File Share but need to maintain the ability to mount them as network drives for the users. we want granular control and would like to use Identity-based access but it's not configured, do i need to leverage Azure AD DS for allow this or is there another approach?

Azure is the basic version do we need to assign a user a p1 or p2 licence?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to leverage Azure AD for authentication with Azure Files is to use AD DS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable?tabs=azure-portal

According to the prerequisites, you do not require a P1/P2 license to leverage this, however if you want to use Self Service Password Resets (SSPR - which is recommended) you will need at least a P1 license for your users.